# multiplying two floats in C++ give me non-number result

Tags: c++

I am a C++ newbie and having a problem with my first program. I'm trying to multiply two float numbers and the result always show like 1.1111e+1 where 1s are the random numbers. Following is the little program I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  float bank;
  float dollor;
  cout<<"Enter amount of $ deposited at Bank: ";//the data to input is 5000
  cin>>bank;
  cout<<"Enter current $ price: ";//1usd = 800mmk: the data to input is 800
  cin>>dollor;
  bank*=dollor;//all deposited $ to local currency
  cout<<"Result is "<<bank;
  getch();
}
```

and the result of this program is 4e+006.

ps: I declared as float in order to input floats sometime.
Please help me with this program where I was wrong. Thanks all..

Comment: -1: Looks like the right answer to me.

Comment: +1 because I think it is a valid question, even though the answer is something I learned in middle school.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`4e+006` is the [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for `4000000`, which is the correct answer to `5000*800`.

To elaborate, `4e+006` stands for `4 * 10**6`, where `10**6` is ten to the sixth power.

To use the fixed-point notation, you could change your program like so:

```
#include <iomanip>
...
cout << "Result is " << fixed << bank;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, 5000 by 800 is indeed 4e6, that is 4*10^6, 4,000,000.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#include <iomanip>

//...
cout << "Result is "<< setprecision(2) << bank;
```

or...

```
cout.precision(2);
cout << "Result is " << fixed << bank;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in scientific notation.

Take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/). Among other things, it shows how you can print a number in fixed-point notation.